# What happens with the decedents' estate when a person dies whilst in a rolling contract?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

If a person dies whilst in a rolling contract, and payments are still taken from the account for a few months,would the company be legally forced to return the money to the account?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch As far as I can tell, "decedent" is not a commonly-understood word; the web suggests it is a US legal term. How would you feel about "the deceased" instead?

Answer (score 2):

**Short version:** No. The deceased tenant's estate remains liable for the rent until the tenancy is ended, typically by the person representing the estate giving notice to the landlord to end the tenancy.

**Long version:**

[This article](http://www.landlordlawblog.co.uk/2014/05/21/what-happens-to-a-tenancy-when-the-tenant-dies/) by Tessa J Shepperson on the Landlord Law Blog covers this in some detail.

Quoting the relevant parts:

> First off – a tenancy does not end when the tenant dies.  What happens depends on the circumstances.

Regarding periodic (rolling) tenancies:

> If there is no-one eligible to succeed to the tenancy under the ‘succession’ provisions of the Rent Act 1977 or the Housing Act 1988, then the tenancy will, as with a fixed term tenancy, pass to the tenant’s Personal Representatives as part of his estate.

Also:

> If the tenancy is a periodic one, then the Personal Representatives will be able to serve a notice to quit on the landlord and end the tenancy that way.

And:

> What usually happens if that the landlord will want to take the property back and re-let it.  However he does not have the right to just do this, unless this is with agreement with the tenant’s Personal Representatives.

Comment: What if the contract doesn't concern a tenancy?

Comment: It may depend on the terms of the contract, or on the relevant area of law.  (I assumed a tenancy, as the term "rolling contract" is commonly used to refer to a periodic tenancy).

Comment: The other place they are common is mobile-phone and broadband contracts.